# What file systems are used on the Xbox 360 and Xbox One? And is there any PC program that will let me see the drive on Windows?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

I would like to find out what file system is being used so that I can try and find a program that will let my PC see the contents on an Xbox drive, for the purpose of data recovery. Has anyone had any luck doing that? I am going to try EaseUS Data Recovery first, but I don't think it will let me add or modify files, just recover them to the PC.

Comment: We don't do recommendations here unfortunately.  And this dances around being a game design and development question.

Comment: We've done console file system question before. This becomes important to users if we ever need to install a new harddrive, or something similar. We propably can answer the feasibility of doing a back up as well as long as we don't need to point to a spesific software.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem, where we're asked for a specific solution, instead of the actual problem.  If this were edited to ask what problem, exactly, this solution is attempting to solve, we might have an answerable question.

Comment: I stated the purpose. Data recovery of files on the drive, both media and save files. I "raw" cloned the failing drive, bit by bit, to another drive with Paragon Drive Copy. If you know what file system it uses, this will help me so I can search for a data recovery program that can see that particular file system.

Comment: Why exactly can you not recommend a particular program??? I have had people recommend a particular video game that meats my criteria, why is this any different?

Comment: Because we don't do recommendations here. No one here has recommended video games for you.

Comment: So which stack IS the right one for recommendations? As far as I can see this is the only video games stack. It seems incredibly silly to not allow game recommendations on a site about video games.

Comment: @Braden'sPC's There's a lengthy meta post describing why we don't do recommendations. You could try [softwarerecs.se]. Or, you could reword your question and title to ask specifically about how to perform data recovery, as opposed to looking for recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

They use a custom file system called FATX. Windows (at least historically) has not supported reading these, but there is limited support found on Linux and MacOS.

If you're just looking to make a full disk backup, taking a full disk image backup is a safer bet than attempting to read/write on the file system level.